# array at size/2 is always undefined

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I'm having a really strange error relating to my array always being undefined at size/2. I have an linked stack and each node contains an array of size `32000` , the problem is that at location `16000` of each array the value is undefined for some reason.

the node is:

```
template <class myType>
struct nodeType {
  myType dataSet[SIZE];
  int top;
  nodeType<myType> *link;
};
```

and the simple push and pop are:

```
template <class myType>
void linkedStack<myType>::push(const myType& newItem)
{
    //if the count is greater than the size of one node's array, create another
    if(count % SIZE == 0) {
      nodeType<myType> *newNode = new nodeType<myType>;
      newNode->top = 0;
      newNode->link = stackTop;
      stackTop = newNode;
    }
    stackTop->dataSet[stackTop->top] = newItem;
    count++;
    stackTop->top++;
}

template <class myType>
void linkedStack<myType>::pop()
{

  if(stackTop->top == 0) {
    nodeType<myType> *toDelete = stackTop;
    stackTop = stackTop->link;
    delete stackTop;
  }
  stackTop->top--;
  count--;
}
```

and the for loop im using is:

```
for (int i=testSize2; i>0; i--) {
    if (iStackBig.top() != i) {
        workedStk = false;
    }
    iStackBig.pop();
}
```

I just can't understand why location `16000` is undefined in **every** nodes array. am I doing anything obviously wrong?

Comment: And it doesn't happen with arrays of size 31998?

Comment: This is *begging* for a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just curious, stackTop->top++ and -- are working as you expect?

Comment: Where you have `delete stackTop` - do you mean `delete toDelete` ?

Comment: What do you mean it's "undefined"?

Comment: How big does your stack grow?  What type is count variable?

Comment: What is the definition of count and where is it defined?

Comment: How come in the `pop`, you delete `stackTop` and after it you use it in `stackTop->top--`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I see:

```
if (stackTop->top == 0) {
    nodeType<myType> *toDelete = stackTop;
    stackTop = stackTop->link;
    delete stackTop;          // You should be deleting toDelete here
} 
stackTop->top--;    // Oops, just used a deleted pointer
```

Using a previously deleted pointer invokes undefined behaviour which could well be the source of your problem. You should also be checking if `stackTop` or `stackTop->link` is NULL at some point when you pop from an empty stack.

Comment: yep, that's the simple mistake I knew I must have been doing. Thanks!